# Como manter um programa rodando porém com execução perene em certos período de tempo

Tags: python, if, while

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em python onde quero emular um envio de email onde de 5 em 5 minutos o usuário receba uma mensagem em sua caixa de entrada, estou com certas dificuldades, estou utilizando o `datetime`, `if` e `while`, porém o programa só executa uma vez o que devo fazer?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

complementando a resposta do parceiro, dentro do time.sleep(60) o valor 60 se refere ao tempo em segundos, para 5 minutos deve colocar time.sleep(300)

Answer (score -2):

Pode fazer assim:

```
  import time
    
    def envia_email():
        pass
    
    while True:
        envia_email()# def onde vai enviar email
        time.sleep(60)#Espera 5 minutos ate enviar outro e-mail
```